# Connecting Qt GUI to python code in QGIS Plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, pyqt, qt-designer

I am completely new to PyQGIS/PyQt and am having lots of trouble getting started. I have managed to create my base dialog box like so:

[image: base_dialog]

The (automatically generated) code for the dialog is:

```
import os

from qgis.PyQt import uic
from qgis.PyQt import QtWidgets

# This loads your .ui file so that PyQt can populate your plugin with the elements from Qt Designer
FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'offshore_interpretation_dialog_base.ui'))


class InterpretationDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Constructor."""
        super(InterpretationDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer through FORM_CLASS.
        # After self.setupUi() you can access any designer object by doing
        # self.<objectname>, and you can use autoconnect slots - see
        # http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html
        # #widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect
        self.setupUi(self)
```

In my `run` method for my plugin I have tried this (and various other things):

```
def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""

        # Create the dialog with elements (after translation) and keep reference
        # Only create GUI ONCE in callback, so that it will only load when the plugin is started
        if self.first_start == True:
            self.first_start = False
            self.dlg = OffshoreInterpretationDialog()

        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
            #interpret_checkBox/qc_checkBox are names I gave in QT designer for the checkboxes
            if self.dlg.interpret_checkBox.isChecked(): 
                print ('You have selected interpretation')
            elif self.dlg.qc_checkBox.isChecked():
                print ('You have selected qc')
            else:
                print ('Please select an option')
```

Content of .ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>OffshoreInterpretationDialogBase</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="OffshoreInterpretationDialogBase">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>350</width>
    <height>166</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>OffshoreInterpretation</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QDialogButtonBox" name="button_box">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>120</y>
     <width>161</width>
     <height>32</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="orientation">
    <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="standardButtons">
    <set>QDialogButtonBox::Cancel|QDialogButtonBox::Ok</set>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="Title">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>351</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <pointsize>13</pointsize>
     <weight>50</weight>
     <bold>false</bold>
    </font>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Offshore Exploration Slick Interpretation Tool</string>
   </property>
   <property name="textFormat">
    <enum>Qt::AutoText</enum>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QCheckBox" name="interpret_checkBox">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>50</y>
     <width>151</width>
     <height>31</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <pointsize>11</pointsize>
    </font>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Interpret New Slicks</string>
   </property>
   <property name="iconSize">
    <size>
     <width>16</width>
     <height>16</height>
    </size>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QCheckBox" name="qc_checkBox">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>80</y>
     <width>151</width>
     <height>31</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <pointsize>11</pointsize>
    </font>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>QC Existing Slicks</string>
   </property>
   <property name="iconSize">
    <size>
     <width>16</width>
     <height>16</height>
    </size>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>button_box</sender>
   <signal>accepted()</signal>
   <receiver>OffshoreInterpretationDialogBase</receiver>
   <slot>accept()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>20</x>
     <y>20</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>20</x>
     <y>20</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>button_box</sender>
   <signal>rejected()</signal>
   <receiver>OffshoreInterpretationDialogBase</receiver>
   <slot>reject()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>20</x>
     <y>20</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>20</x>
     <y>20</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
</ui>
```

I get an Error saying `AttributeError: 'InterpretationDialog' object has no attribute 'interpret_checkBox'`

I don't understand how I can access the methods and attributes of the checkBox buttons (or any other buttons) in the code. Where do I find the documentation for all of this? I have tried to follow many tutorials but none explain how I can see which methods are available for each object?

I am using QGIS 3.4 and am horribly lost.

Comment: You should check the widget name in Qt Designer or in the .ui file. The case of the letters count!

Comment: Obviously, the name of `Interpret` checkbox is not `interpret_checkBox`. Please add `offshore_interpretation_dialog_base.ui` file content to get help.

Comment: @Zoltan i've added the content of the .ui file- one of the cases was wrong but i'm still getting the error message. Where is the official documentation? I'm having trouble finding it?

Comment: Convert `self.dlg = OffshoreInterpretationDialog()` to `self.dlg = InterpretationDialog()` in `run`method. If it doesn't help, please share files of your plugin. You added the scripts partially. It makes it hard to understand what problem is.

Comment: Your "check boxes" don't work because you're putting your lines in the wrong place (run method). Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your "check boxes" don't work because you're putting your lines in the wrong place (**run** method). However, you need first to declare objects in **__init__** method for connecting them to a 'change_status' function (preferably one for each check box). I'm going to exemplify this only for "Interpretation" Check Box. Snippet code is as follows:

```
.
.
.
def __init__(self, iface): 
        """Constructor."""
.
.
.
    chkBox1 = self.dlg.interpret_checkBox
    chkBox1.setChecked(True)
    chkBox1.setText('Interpretation')
    chkBox1.stateChanged.connect(self.change_status_interpretation)

    chkBox2 = self.dlg.qc_checkBox
    chkBox2.stateChanged.connect(self.change_status_qc)
.
.
.
    def change_status_interpretation(self):

        if self.dlg.interpret_checkBox.isChecked():
            self.dlg.interpret_checkBox.setText("Interpretation")
            print ('You have selected interpretation')
        else:
            self.dlg.interpret_checkBox.setText("Check to activate interpretation")

    def change_status_qc(self):

        pass #your code here

    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""
.
.
.
```

I put above lines in my test plugin and launched it. It can be observed in following image. It is checked by default.

[image]

When it is unchecked, text in Check Box automatically changes to "Check to activate interpretation"; as it can be observed in following image:

[image]

When it is checked again, it is printed in Python Console "You have selected interpretation" and text Check Box changes to "Interpretation". This can be observed in following image:

[image]